# Arduino micro usb

Tags: arduino, usb

I have an Arduino Micro that is going to be mounted inside an enclosure in which it would be a pain to open the enclosure to adjust programming. Is there a way that I can access the DATA+ and DATA- signals of the USB so that I can create external connector? I rather not use some sort of FTDI breakout when the Micro already has USB built in. I feel like soldering to the pin on the USB connector would be near impossible.

Comment: Just use a USB cable with a USB connector on the other end? Like one side has a micro usb which you can plug into the arduino, and the other has a female Type A USB connector. The connector is outside the enclosure.

Comment: USB wants a differential (twisted-pair) controlled-impedance signalling pair, otherwise it will not be reliable and might not work at all. Tee connections are not advised for USB. You're better off just using the connector.

Comment: yea i feel like that is what i am going to end up doing, but I was wondering if there was some pins or another way that i didn't know of

Comment: FYI you can also flash the Atmel ATmega328 microcontroller's firmware using the ISP protocol, all you need are the SPI signals, RESET, Ground, and VCC.

Comment: More about ISP programming here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/25144/programming-via-isp and also on Nick Gammon's blog.

Comment: I had a similar need. I spliced a micro USB plug to one of these: https://aliexpress.com/item/USB-2-0-B-Male-to-USB-B-Female-Socket-Printer-Panel-Mount-Extension-50cm-Cable/32475012064.html I used a right angle plug to use less space. I couldn't find the micro USB equivalent of that panel mount extension. I like the panel mount USB jack and it's much more durable than the one on the Micro, which breaks off fairly easily. You need to watch out with those cheap cables, sometimes the wire colors don't correspond to the standard USB pins so you have to do a continuity test on each one to check.

Comment: https://www.adafruit.com/products/3258

Answer (score 1):

You can get a USB extention cable with panel-mount female end. That would allow you to mount the female connector on the outside of your case and plug the male end of the cable into the board.  One example of a source:

[image: USB Micro Extention cable]
https://www.adafruit.com/products/936
Likely available from several other vendors.

Comment: The Arduino Micro has a Micro-B USB jack on(that one has a Mini-B plug) so https://www.adafruit.com/products/3258 would be the correct item. Thanks to @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams for pointing out the link to me!